# If I write a handler with to handle path *, will it have the same functionality as a httpmodule?

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler, httpmodule

```
 <handlers>
      <add name="TextHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="TextHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
 </handlers>
```

I know that `httphandlers` are for handling file extensions, `httpmodule's` seems to have a bit of a wider "net".
 As far as I can see, that is the only difference, and it's fairly semantic, because the pertinent functionality is set in the Web.config file anyway.
 For example, element above caters for any path, or no specific path.
 With this, don't I basically have a httpmodule?
 Or are there deeper differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a single handler handles a request. Many modules may handle the request.

So, no, not the same.